# Android : simple_list_item_activated_1 : Listview change default blue color

Tags: android, css, listview

I am trying to develop a quiz app with previous & Next button.  I am able to highlight the selected item in listview when i press or touch.
but unable to highlight the row with custom color when i do it programitically.

**Issue**

When I press the Previous button a query is run which check if the user has selected an option for that particukar question If yes, then the item at that position is slected and also highlighted, but the highlighted color is blue .
that is of the theme app.combat.light I guess.

**How i set item checked :**

```
listviewoptions.setItemChecked(iposition, true);
//here iposition is a int variable called from db via query.
```

**Code for binding it to list**

```
List<String> options = db.getAllOptions(QuestionID);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1, options);

        listviewoptions.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I have also tried to use my own custom list... but didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what you are doing in program is fine but use a custom layout for the simple list item. I believe you are using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1.

Create your own item layout since is just a textView Like this

**your.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/yourselector" />
```

then define a selector in drawable

**yourselector.xml**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/color_slide_menu_item_pressed" />
    </shape>   
</item>

<item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/color_slide_menu_item_activated" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/color_main_theme_background" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**Note:**  Define your own color, you may define it there directly or some other color resource

Then on your adapter change the layout

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
```

to

```
R.layout.your
```

Answer (score 1):

On your list item which has been clicked you need to call:

```
selectedItemView.setActivated(true);
```

And your list selector state drawable should declare this state:

```
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey_07" android:state_activated="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```